# List All Un-authrorized Truslines

Tags: stellar-core, assets, trustline, authorization

I want to activate `AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED` and `AUTHORIZATION REVOCABLE` flags on my asset issuing account. How can I get list of all unauthorized trustlines after I activate those two flags?

I have my own Stellar Core. I assume that I can get that data from `trustlines` table in Core database with `flags` equal to `0`. Can someone please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you can retrieve accounts with pending authorization by querying `trustlines` table.

`SELECT accountid FROM trustlines WHERE flags=0 AND assetcode='MYASSET';`